# Suitability for using a standard light switch to connect to a micro-controller port

Tags: resistance

Could a standard run of the mill Lightswitch like this:

[image]

Be used in place of a button like this on a microcontroller project:
[image]

I'm not in any way suggesting I'm tapped into the house electricity. Literally curious if these larger switches could be used as substitutes or if there would be some reason like some standard resistances that would impede usage at the lower energy levels (3v/5v) sources one would use when experimenting with micro controllers.

For example could this be awkwardly wired to a GPIO port on a Raspberry Pi or Arduino compatible controller and be expected to function appropriately?

Comment: Keep in mind you're comparing a rocker toggle switch to a momentary one

Comment: If you are using it with a pull-up resistor, use a smaller value if possible to reduce the risk of dry contacts. Maybe 1k instead of 10k.

Answer (score 5):

In general, yes, you can use these on microcontroller circuits.

You are correct that contact resistance could be a problem. With mains voltage any layer of grime on the contacts will be broken down by the high electric field due to the high voltage. On a 3.3 V or 5 V circuit you may experience some problems such as contact bounce.

I wouldn't anticipate any trouble with switches that hadn't been used much on mains for any significant service.

Answer (score 1):

Gold-plated contact switches are rated up to 2A and carbon momentary buttons don't oxidize.

All the others do. Even the good ones with silver alloys with high temp Palladium alloys. They still oxide and become insulators. So they don't work well for microamps or even milliamps.

The cheap fix is to put a 10kohm pullup R to 3.3 or 5V logic levels and a 10uF tantalum cap (polarized to ground) to discharge and provide a "wetting" arc current to clean off the oxide on each use. The side benefit is when the product of R*C is greater than the contact bounce time, possibly 25 milliseconds , it removes the voltage glitch.